# php upload smaller image version of original

Tags: php, image, upload, webserver

I'm new to php and I've managed to get uploading images working to my webserver.
Now I'm looking for a way to also upload a smaller duplicate version of the original image to my webserver.

For example the original image that is uploaded is image1_timestamp.jpg
I also want the same image with a max width of 700px, image1_timestamp_700w.jpg without loosing the image with/hight ratio.

This is my current code

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
    echo "Error Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
} else {
    echo "Uploaded file: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kilobytes<br />";

    if (file_exists("/files/".$_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
        echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists";
    } else {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"/var/www/mydomain.com/docs/files/images/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        echo "Done";
    }
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Try this reference http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote something for you :

Please keep using : DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR const

```
<?php
    /**
     *  @brief Resize an image with keeping aspect ratio
     *  
     *  @param [in] $src_image_path :: Source image path => "C:\www\abstract.jpg"
     *  @param [in] $dst_image_path :: Destination image path => "C:\www\abstract2.jpg"
     *  @param [in] $new_width :: Width aspect ratio => "700"
     *  @return image
     *  
     */
    function resizeImage($src_image_path, $dst_image_path, $new_width) {
        $mime = getimagesize($src_image_path);

        if($mime['mime']=='image/png'){ $src_img = imagecreatefrompng($src_image_path); }
        if($mime['mime']=='image/jpg'){ $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($src_image_path); }
        if($mime['mime']=='image/jpeg'){ $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($src_image_path); }
        if($mime['mime']=='image/pjpeg'){ $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($src_image_path); }

        $aspect = $mime[1] / $mime[0];

        $new_height = $aspect * $new_width;

        $old_x          =   imageSX($src_img);
        $old_y          =   imageSY($src_img);

        $dst_img        =   ImageCreateTrueColor($new_width,$new_height);

        imagecopyresampled($dst_img,$src_img,0,0,0,0,$new_width,$new_height,$old_x,$old_y); 

        // Quality compression : From 0 to 100
        $jpg_quality = 90;

        // Quality compression : From 0 to 9
        $png_quality = 8;

        if($mime['mime']=='image/png'){ $result = imagepng($dst_img, $dst_image_path, $png_quality); }
        if($mime['mime']=='image/jpg'){ $result = imagejpeg($dst_img, $dst_image_path, $jpg_quality); }
        if($mime['mime']=='image/jpeg'){ $result = imagejpeg($dst_img, $dst_image_path, $jpg_quality); }
        if($mime['mime']=='image/pjpeg'){ $result = imagejpeg($dst_img, $dst_image_path, $jpg_quality); }

        imagedestroy($dst_img); 
        imagedestroy($src_img);

        return $result;
    }

    $currentPath = dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

    echo $currentPath;

    resizeImage($currentPath . 'abstract.jpg', $currentPath . 'abstract2.jpg', 700);
?>
```

**EDIT** For your case, this would probably work :

```
<?php
    $newWidth = 700;
    $savePath = "/var/www/mydomain.com/docs/files/images/" .$_FILES["file"]["name"];

    if($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "Error Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }else {
        echo "Uploaded file: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kilobytes<br />";

        if(file_exists($savePath)) {
            echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists";
        }else {
            resizeImage($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $savePath, $newWidth);
            echo "Done";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this nice looking code!! maybe this sounds stupid but I have no idea if this completely replaces my current code or where I have to add this to my current code? 
The way I understand it wright now is that I have to call this code (function) after I have uploaded the original file ?
The Source image path (C:\www\abstract.jpg) I have to replace with /var/www/mydomain.com/docs/files/images/$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]
and Destination image path (C:\www\abstract2.jpg) I have to replace with /var/www/mydomain.com/docs/files/images/mysmallerimagenewname.jpg

Comment: Yes, you have to replace with ur own filename for source and destination. See the response, i add ur case.

Comment: Can you also help me with adding image rotation fix of images uploaded from iphone and android devices ?